# Upload a video to Facebook Graph API, and tag a place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to "attach" a page to an uploaded video (via graph api) on Facebook, without any luck.

Creating a post (via `/feed` endpoint) and tagging on a place is working. Sharing a picture and tagging on a place is working. But not videos.

As I've seen in the [official docummentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video#Updating), the flow to "attach" a `page` is to use resumable uploads and then update the video via `POST /<video_id>` with `{ place: <page_id> }`. But it's not working at all, besides the fact the API is returning `{ success: true }`

I've also tried other alternatives:

- Upload the video at once (not resumable).
- Just specify the video url (not even getting the `<video_id>`).
- Doing the `POST /<video_id>` update request via their Graph API explorer console.

I'm using version 2.8, the graph-video endpoint and have `publish_actions` permissions.

What could I be doing wrong? How do you do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do this via the Graph Video api. The final solution for me was to create a feed post, via `/me/feed` specifying:

```
{
  place: pageId,
  coordinates: '{latitude,longitude}'
  link: 'url'
}
```

being `link` an url pointing to a website that have the proper Open Graph attributes.